# FormGroup get field value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

I'm trying make a validation for "passwordConfirm" field, but i get a stange error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`
here is my code:

```typescript
loginForm: FormGroup;


ngOnInit(){
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      'password': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'passwordConfirm': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, this.checkIfMatchingPasswords.bind(this)]),
    });
}



checkIfMatchingPasswords() {
    return this.loginForm.get('password').value === this.loginForm.get('passwordConfirm').value ? null : { notSame: true} // error
  }
```

Comment: Try `if(!this.loginForm) {return null}`  in your custom validator.

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: very strange but you could try this.loginForm.controls['controlname'].value

Comment: in the checkIfMatchingPasswords() scope, this.loginForm is undefined

Comment: now i understand, this is not a validator but a pure function. you have to do something else i guess like callinng this function on value changes on passwordConfirm or submit instead of in validation.

Comment: All I need is a validator for matching passwords

Comment: check this link for validators  [template driven](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/template) & [data driven](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive)

Comment: Have you add `[formGroup]="loginForm"` in your html?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve by binding `this` to your validator is probably failing as multiple validator functions are merged into a single function where the context is likely different.

However, if you follow the footprint of a [validator function](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn), you can do the following:

```
checkIfMatchingPasswords(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return control.root.get('password').value === control.value ? null : { notSame: true };
}
```

The trick is that each `AbstractControl` knows its [parent](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#parent) and [root](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#root).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to check if the loginForm exists. If i do a console.log of `this.loginForm` it executes for three times. The first time is undefined, and was causing the error. I don't know why it happens, maybe that are Angular's life cycle hooks.

```
  checkIfMatchingPasswords() {
    if (this.loginForm) {
      return this.loginForm.get('password').value === this.loginForm.get('passwordConfirm').value ? null : {notSame: true};
    }
  }
```

Comment: Well this is basically what I said, but instead of `if(this.loginForm)` I said `if(!this.loginForm) { return null } ....rest of code here...` But any of these ways works tho.

Comment: You just have to remember that with this solution it only validates when `passwordConfirm` is modified :)